# Normals aren't baking properly

Tags: normal-map

So the other day I was making a window frame and baking to a plane..Got my results.. Then, Made several out of planes..baked, worked fine..

Now.. I am making a building model and tried the same thing...Horrible results.

Can anyone look at this and give me some ideas? Thanks.

Both models are in same exact location..I have tried different shaders.. I'm trying to keep tri and vert count low as possible as it's a mobile game.

First image shows the window frame..second the ugly normal being baked..then low pol and high pol meshes.

I'm relatively new and this is my learning model so I want to perfect everything possible on this model before I move on to the next.

[image: Windows to be normalized onto low poly]

[image: The ugly normals]

[image: The low poly and UV layout]

[image: The "high" poly and UV layout]

Comment: How do I check for this? It's a new blank image and "clear" is selected on bake

Comment: To check what? What you are trying to do is impossible, normal maps do not capture depth, only the angle of the faces.

Comment: How is it impossible? Earlier with a flat plane i extruded edges and made a window frame.. then baked normals and had the illusion of the window frame on a flat plane.. which is what I'm trying to do on the face of these walls...

Comment: I think I get what you are saying. So if I scale inward to create an "angle" before extruding I should get the effect?

Comment: Also, that purple is quite dark. Are you using sRGB instead of Non-Color Data?